# Website creation for multiple clients but from a single account on multiple host name

Tags: multisite, domain

This might seem to be 2 tricky questions but I have searched on net but didn't find the exact answer.

I know that we can have Wordpress multisite to handle multiple websites with a single Wordpress account BUT they can be deployed on the same hostname.

Q1) Now, suppose that I create Wordpress websites, for multiple clients, so can I use the same Wordpress account for all the clients, OR do I have to install and create different Wordpress accounts for all the clients on their own respective domain/hostname?

The second question is like a follow-up to Q1.

Q2) The reason I am asking is that suppose I purchased PRO version of Elementor Plugin from my Wordpress account, and use it for all my client websites (on different domains) but by accessing it from one Wordpress account? Or do I have to keep purchasing Pro version for all the different client websites?

Comment: 1. Multisite supports different domains for different sites. They don’t have to be on the same domain. 2. Questions about licenses should be asked to the plugin developer. Multisite only need one install, so you should be ok for updates, but they may not support you for other sites. But honestly, if you can’t afford a license for each site, you’re not charging enough.

Comment: In my experience, some plugins offer licensing for a Multisite network, while others only offer per-site licensing. As @JacobPeattie says, you'll need to check with the plugin developers.